# Polynomial Simplification

Tags: symbolic-computation, maxima-software

I've been working with Maxima and its thrown me an expression like this

$$
\left( \left( \left( 6\,{w}_{1}-6\right) \,{p}_{2}-6\,{p}_{1}\,{w}_{1}+6\,{p}_{0}\right) \,{w}_{2}^{2}+\left( \left( 6\,{w}_{1}-6\,{w}_{1}^{2}\right) \,{p}_{2}+6\,{p}_{1}\,{w}_{1}^{2}+\left( 6\,{p}_{1}-12\,{p}_{0}\right) \,{w}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{2}+\left( 6\,{p}_{0}-6\,{p}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{1}^{2}\right) \,{t}_{3}+\left( \left( \left( 6-6\,{w}_{1}\right) \,{t}_{2}+6\,{t}_{1}\,{w}_{1}-6\,{t}_{0}\right) \,{w}_{2}^{2}+\left( \left( 6\,{w}_{1}^{2}-6\,{w}_{1}\right) \,{t}_{2}-6\,{t}_{1}\,{w}_{1}^{2}+\left( 12\,{t}_{0}-6\,{t}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{2}+\left( 6\,{t}_{1}-6\,{t}_{0}\right) \,{w}_{1}^{2}\right) \,{p}_{3}+\left( \left( 6\,{p}_{0}\,{w}_{1}-6\,{p}_{0}\right) \,{t}_{2}+\left( 6\,{t}_{0}-6\,{t}_{0}\,{w}_{1}\right) \,{p}_{2}+\left( 6\,{t}_{0}\,{p}_{1}-6\,{p}_{0}\,{t}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{2}^{2}+\left( \left( 6\,{p}_{0}\,{w}_{1}-6\,{p}_{0}\,{w}_{1}^{2}\right) \,{t}_{2}+\left( 6\,{t}_{0}\,{w}_{1}^{2}-6\,{t}_{0}\,{w}_{1}\right) \,{p}_{2}+\left( 6\,{p}_{0}\,{t}_{1}-6\,{t}_{0}\,{p}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{1}^{2}+\left( 6\,{p}_{0}\,{t}_{1}-6\,{t}_{0}\,{p}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{2}+\left( 6\,{t}_{0}\,{p}_{1}-6\,{p}_{0}\,{t}_{1}\right) \,{w}_{1}^{2}
$$

I can see that this polynomial can be simplified, e.g. over 3 dozen multiplications by 6 can be replaced by a single multiplication by 6, and lots of computations of $t_1 - t_0$ can be precomputed. This is important because I'm going to evaluating this expression (and others like it, generated by Maxima) hundreds of thousands of times in a computer program. Can anyone recommend a symbolic maths application that does a better job than Maxima on such tasks.

Here is the formula readable for Maxima:

```
(((6*w[1]-6)*p[2]-6*p[1]*w[1]+6*p[0])*w[2]^2+((6*w[1]-6*w[1]^2)*p[2]+6*p[1]*w[1]^2+(6*p[1]-12*p[0])*w[1])*w[2]+(6*p[0]-6*p[1])*w[1]^2)*t[3]+(((6-6*w[1])*t[2]+6*t[1]*w[1]-6*t[0])*w[2]^2+((6*w[1]^2-6*w[1])*t[2]-6*t[1]*w[1]^2+(12*t[0]-6*t[1])*w[1])*w[2]+(6*t[1]-6*t[0])*w[1]^2)*p[3]+((6*p[0]*w[1]-6*p[0])*t[2]+(6*t[0]-6*t[0]*w[1])*p[2]+(6*t[0]*p[1]-6*p[0]*t[1])*w[1])*w[2]^2+((6*p[0]*w[1]-6*p[0]*w[1]^2)*t[2]+(6*t[0]*w[1]^2-6*t[0]*w[1])*p[2]+(6*p[0]*t[1]-6*t[0]*p[1])*w[1]^2+(6*p[0]*t[1]-6*t[0]*p[1])*w[1])*w[2]+(6*t[0]*p[1]-6*p[0]*t[1])*w[1]^2
```

Comment: I know a few tricks I can try  but your formula is too complicated to type without errors. If you can copy the expression (not the Tex form) I can give it a shot

Comment: Here you go http://pastebin.com/bsizpcR3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Almost 10 years later)

The [SCOPE package](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/reduce38-docs/scope.pdf) of the [reduce algebra system](https://reduce-algebra.sourceforge.io/documentation38.php) does just this.

The [coeff2 package](https://reduce-algebra.sourceforge.io/manual/manualse136.html#x201-49700020.13) too is immensely useful in simplifying expressions.

**Input**:

```
off fancy,echo,raise,lower$

load_package scope$

optimize f :=: (((6*w1-6)*p2-6*p1*w1+6*p0)*w2^2+((6*w1-6*w1^2)*p2+6*p1*w1^2+(6*p1-12*p0)*w1)*w2+(6*p0-6*p1)*w1^2)*t3+(((6-6*w1)*t2+6*t1*w1-6*t0)*w2^2+((6*w1^2-6*w1)*t2-6*t1*w1^2+(12*t0-6*t1)*w1)*w2+(6*t1-6*t0)*w1^2)*p3+((6*p0*w1-6*p0)*t2+(6*t0-6*t0*w1)*p2+(6*t0*p1-6*p0*t1)*w1)*w2^2+((6*p0*w1-6*p0*w1^2)*t2+(6*t0*w1^2-6*t0*w1)*p2+(6*p0*t1-6*t0*p1)*w1^2+(6*p0*t1-6*t0*p1)*w1)*w2+(6*t0*p1-6*p0*t1)*w1^2;
```

**Output**:

```
g65 := w2*w2
g54 := g65*p3
g66 := w1*w1
g51 := g66*w2
g53 := g65*p2
g60 := t3*w2
g52 := g65*w1
g63 := w1*p0
g61 := w2*w1
g67 := 6*(p3*t2*w2 - g60*p2)
g68 := 6*(g54*t2 - g53*t3)
g69 := 6*(g63*t2 - p2*t0*w1)
g72 := 6*t0
g74 := 6*t3
g71 := 6*p0
g73 := 6*t1
g75 := 6*p1
g76 := 6*p3*w1*t1
g77 := 6*g60*p1
f := g68 + (g72 - g74)*(g66*p1 + g52*p1) + w1*(g77 - g68 - g67) + w2*(g69 - g76) + t0*6*(g53 - g54) + g51*t1*(g71 - 6*p3) + g51*t0*(6*p2 - g75) + g66*p3*(g73 - g72) + g65*p0*(g74 - 6*t2) + g63*w1*(g74 - g73) + g61*t0*(12*p3 - g75) + t1*p0*6*(g61 - g52) + g65*(g76 + g69) + g66*(g77 + g67) - 12*g63*g60 - g71*g51*t2
```

*I am marking this as the answer because, as shown, the SCOPE package relieves its user of the burden of providing any sight into the formulae to be simplified. Also, in contrast to Maple, the reduce-algebra system and packages are freely available*.

Answer (score 0):

If I set $X$ to the expression and execute ***factor(X)*** I get
$$6\,\left(w_{2}-w_{1}\right)\,\left(w_{1}\,p_{2}\,w_{2}\,t_{3}-p_{2}
 \,w_{2}\,t_{3}-p_{1}\,w_{1}\,w_{2}\,t_{3}+p_{0}\,w_{2}\,t_{3}+p_{1}
 \,w_{1}\,t_{3}-p_{0}\,w_{1}\,t_{3}-w_{1}\,t_{2}\,w_{2}\,p_{3}+t_{2}
 \,w_{2}\,p_{3}+t_{1}\,w_{1}\,w_{2}\,p_{3}-t_{0}\,w_{2}\,p_{3}-t_{1}
 \,w_{1}\,p_{3}+t_{0}\,w_{1}\,p_{3}+p_{0}\,w_{1}\,t_{2}\,w_{2}-p_{0}
 \,t_{2}\,w_{2}-t_{0}\,w_{1}\,p_{2}\,w_{2}+t_{0}\,p_{2}\,w_{2}-p_{0}
 \,t_{1}\,w_{1}\,w_{2}+t_{0}\,p_{1}\,w_{1}\,w_{2}+p_{0}\,t_{1}\,w_{1}
 -t_{0}\,p_{1}\,w_{1}\right)$$

Not sure what further simplification is possible.

**Added in response to comment**

Here is how I would isolate the $w$'s (you can do the same for other variables also:

```
X:(((6*w[1]-6)*p[2]-6*p[1]*w[1]+6*p[0])*w[2]^2+((6*w[1]-6*w[1]^2)*p[2]+6*p[1]*w[1]^2+(6*p[1]-12*p[0])*w[1])*w[2]+(6*p[0]-6*p[1])*w[1]^2)*t[3]+(((6-6*w[1])*t[2]+6*t[1]*w[1]-6*t[0])*w[2]^2+((6*w[1]^2-6*w[1])*t[2]-6*t[1]*w[1]^2+(12*t[0]-6*t[1])*w[1])*w[2]+(6*t[1]-6*t[0])*w[1]^2)*p[3]+((6*p[0]*w[1]-6*p[0])*t[2]+(6*t[0]-6*t[0]*w[1])*p[2]+(6*t[0]*p[1]-6*p[0]*t[1])*w[1])*w[2]^2+((6*p[0]*w[1]-6*p[0]*w[1]^2)*t[2]+(6*t[0]*w[1]^2-6*t[0]*w[1])*p[2]+(6*p[0]*t[1]-6*t[0]*p[1])*w[1]^2+(6*p[0]*t[1]-6*t[0]*p[1])*w[1])*w[2]+(6*t[0]*p[1]-6*p[0]*t[1])*w[1]^2;

Y:factor(X/(6*(w[1]-w[2])))$
    C:factor(diff(diff(Y,w[1]),w[2]))$
Y2:factor(Y-C*w[1]*w[2])$
    A:diff(Y2,w[1])$
B:diff(Y2, w[2])$
(A*w[1]+B*w[2]+C*w[1]*w[2])*6*(w[1]-w[2]);
factor(%-X);
```

So your expression is 
$$
6 (w_1 - w_2 ) ~(A w_1 + B w_2 + C w_1 w_2)
$$

I use the wxmaxima front end.

Comment: I can see several $w_1w_2$ terms that can be factored out in the inner expression.

Comment: give me a sec...

Comment: Where do those differentials come from? And is there a way to get maxima to take these steps by itself?

Comment: The easiest way to pull the coefficient in front of a variable is to differentiate with respect to the variable (and if necessary evaluate at the variable equal to zero). The command would be something like *subst(V=0, diff(E,V))* where *E* is the expression and *V* is the variable. You can generalize this to *subst(V=0, diff(E/k!,V,k))* for the coefficient of $V^k$. This kind of simplification is *ad-hoc* and so Maxima can't do it automatically. Maxima does provide the tools for you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following.  I obtained this using Maple's codegen[optimize].

```
t30 = w[1]
t28 = t30^2
t42 = 6*t28
t41 = 6*t30
t32 = t[1]
t40 = -6*t32
t34 = p[1]
t39 = 6*t34
t23 = -t30+t28
t29 = w[2]
t38 = t23*t29
t33 = p[2]
t35 = t[0]
t37 = t35*t33
t36 = p[0]
t31 = t[2]
t27 = t29^2
t26 = t41-6
t25 = t36*t30
t22 = t32*t36-t34*t35
t1 = ((t26*t33-6*t30*t34+6*t36)*t27+(t28*t39+(t39-12*t36)*t30)*t29-6*t33*t38+(t36-t34)*t42)*t[3]+((-t26*t31+t32*t41-6*t35)*t27+(t28*t40+(12*t35+t40)*t30)
*t29+6*t31*t38+(t32-t35)*t42)*p[3]+6*((-t36+t25)*t31+t37+(-t22-t37)*t30)*t27+6*((-t28*t36+t25)*t31+t23*t37+(t28+t30)*t22)*t29-6*t22*t28
```